# A Prime Example of a Number Pattern

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Can you fill in the holes in this pattern?

> 361
>   722
>   726
>   [A]
>   323
>   650
>   223
>   49729
>   99458
>   [B]
>   19024
>   2538
>   2240
>   98
>   102
>   302
>   22805
>   [C]

**EDIT**: As the answer has been found, the clues would have been:
1) An edit to the title to be "A Prime Example..."
2) Adding 19 to the beginning of the sequence
3) A link to an online calculator for finding prime factorials
4) The statement that the last clue just about summed it up

---

**Bonus Question:**
What can you choose as the starting number such that the pattern repeats itself forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see a pattern in there, it only works in case one of your calculations is incorrect though.

The solution:

> A = 255, B = 99462, C = 20802746

The incorrect transition:

> 99462 -> 2538, you forgot to mention 19024 in between.

The pattern:

> Take a number, split it into its prime factors, add the square of each prime factor to arrive at the next number.
> Example: 2538 is 2*3*3*3*47, adding the squares is 4+9+9+9+2209, next number is 2240.

Bonus answer:

> Start with 1, you'll stay at that value.

Comment: Amazingly well done. You're right that I missed a step when making my table and dropped 19,024 from the list. I'll put it back in for completeness sake. You missed the bonus question, though, because 1 is not a [prime number](https://oeis.org/A000040) and the only factor of 1 is 1 so it has no prime factors. Figure out a different answer for that and you can have an upvote to go along with the answer acceptance.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case I'll pick 16. :-)

Comment: Spot on. I also would have accepted 27. There aren't any more below 1,000 and I wonder if there are any more at all.

Comment: @EngineerToast For the bonus, I've brute-forced for any cycles (max length 2048, max value 10^50) with starting values from 2 to 100k without finding any other than 16 → 16 and 27 → 27.

Comment: Points for completeness, @LegionMammal978 !